# in codeigniter, I need to use `count` in such a way that

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I need a query that gets number of some occurrences. In other words, I need a CodeIgniter method such that query produces something like:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total FROM comments WHERE `level`= 4
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$this->db->select('count(*)');
$this->db->from('comments');
$this->db->where('level','4');
$query = $this->db->get();
echo $query->num_rows();
```

Comment: I think, this will only give 0 or 1 I think, but I got the the way you think. If this is the case, I will edit it.

Comment: $query->num_rows() will return number of rows. then you shouldn't use $this->db->select('count(*)');. It should be $this->db->select('*');

Answer (score 5):

```
    $this->db->select('count(*) as total');  
    $this->db->from('comments');
    $this->db->where('level', 4);
    $sql   = $this->db->return_query();
    /*debug*/ 
    /*echo 'sql:: '.$sql;*/
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
    $arr   = $query->row_array(); 
    $total = $arr['total'];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM comments WHERE `level`= 4");
echo $query->result_array();
```

**OR**

```
$this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM comments");
$this->db->where("`level`= 4");
```

Comment: I know that but isnt there something similar to $this->db->where(), because I will have lots of $this->db->where() statements.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use

```
$this->db->query('SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total FROM comments WHERE `level`= 4');
```

Comment: I know that but isnt there something similar to $this->db->where(), because I will have lots of $this->db->where() statements.

Comment: @bluebrain:  there is, but why do you need the CI-specific way?  The general mysql access method is shorter and possibly more clear.

Comment: So what is the actual type of the `query` function? a numeric value?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll like similar like this:

```
$count = $this->db->where("level","4")->count_all_results("comments");
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html