# How can represent SQL's `having count('*')` in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This code runs in MySQL without error:

```sql
SELECT
    name, email, COUNT(*)
FROM
    users
GROUP BY
    name, email
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

How can I reproduce this in CodeIgniter? I need to know how can represent `COUNT(*) > 1`.

For example:

```
function duplicate_m()
{
    $q=$this->db->select('*')->group_by(array("name","email"))->get("users"); 
    return $q->result();

}
```

Comment: Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164416/in-codeigniter-i-need-to-use-count-in-such-a-way-that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code

```
function duplicate_m()
    {
        $q=$this->db->select('count(*) as cnt')->group_by(array("name","email"))->having("cnt > 0", null, false)->get("users"); 
        return $q->result();

    }
```

I hope this will help

Comment: First thing Thank you so much it's working with some modify